# Can git submodule manage external repo under non-git version control tools?

Tags: git, version-control

I already know that git can use submodule to manage external repos that also under git's control. Can git submodule manage external repo under non-git version control tools? If it cannot do that, are there any ways to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git submodules are for handling git repos. If your non-git version control system is svn then there is [great built in support](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html). What is the other VCS?

Comment: I am tring to use a package maintained with bzr(bazaar). But this is also helpful, thanks!

Comment: Maybe bzr-git would be useful http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/migration/en/foreign/bzr-on-git-projects.html

Comment: bzr-git lets developers use Bazaar as their VCS client on projects still using Git as their VCS tool. I think git-bzr-ng https://github.com/termie/git-bzr-ng seems more likely as what I need.